# Android penetration test -- file permissions?

Tags: android, file-permissions, chmod

We had a security audit of one of our apps, and got an odd item.  It said that the file permissions on some files had a global read permission set.  Specifically:

```
# find . -perm -0004

./lib
./lib/libcrypto.so
```

Conceptually I understand this, because Android is Linux and it has file permissions as a result.  What I don't know is, How do I set file permissions for the contents of an APK file, so that the file is readable by the user only?  The Linux equivalent would be:

```
 chmod 500 ./lib/libcrypto.so
```

But I assume that I need to do this in the Manifest, or possibly on the file system of the build machine, or something?

Comment: Ask the security auditors to provide any evidence that your app is behaving abnormally. Conversely, if all NDK apps have their `.so` files set to be world-readable, there is probably a reason for this, and you should not be concerned.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I realize that most likely the parent directories are not readable, but the audit must be satisfied to secure the contract.  The specific concern was "A rogue application on the device could leverage this vulnerability to read sensitive data stored by the application." If we're not going to change the permissions, then we need a justification why we are not.

Comment: Are they taking into account the selinux contexts? The files may be isolated by those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set file permissions for the contents of an APK file, so that the file is readable by the user only?

You don't. The permissions on files that are part of the APK are set up by the operating system at install time, and you do not have direct control over that behavior. Moreover, at least on the one test that I did, `.so` files on the `/data` partition are not owned by you (at least on the emulator) and therefore cannot have their permission bits modified by you:

```
root@generic_x86:/data # ls -al app-lib/com.commonsware.android.passwordbox-1/ 
-rwxr-xr-x system   system    1757156 2014-03-15 13:28 libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
-rwxr-xr-x system   system    3491452 2014-03-15 13:28 libsqlcipher_android.so
-rwxr-xr-x system   system     526052 2014-03-15 12:28 libstlport_shared.so
```

You're welcome to do your own analysis of this if you have a rooted device, to see if it behaves differently than does the emulator. Note that I did not find the `.so` files in the location that they did, possibly due to differences in OS level for testing (I tried a 4.3 x86 emulator).

> But I assume that I need to do this in the Manifest, or possibly on the file system of the build machine, or something?

No, there is nothing in any of that that has anything to do with the permission bits on `.so` files on the device.

As I mentioned in the comment, it is up to the security auditors to demonstrate that the behavior of your app is somehow abnormal. Auditors should be able to do this, or admit that your behavior is *not* abnormal, other than that it uses the NDK.

> A rogue application on the device could leverage this vulnerability to read sensitive data stored by the application

Generally speaking, this would not be the case. The `.so` being world-readable does not magically make the application's "sensitive data" world readable. That is still controlled by file permissions on the data itself.